# Controlling Forms based on log in information

Tags: vba, forms, controlling

I'm been teaching myself Microsoft VBA for Applications and I reached a spot where I really need help getting over a hurdle. I have a login form that controls access by opening a specific form based on assigned roles. Everything works, but it allows a person to see all of the members records. I'm trying to restrict the "Form" to the user who's logged in.  Below is the code that I have for logging in.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim User As String
Dim UserLevel As Integer
Dim TempPass As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim Username As String
Dim TempID As String

If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Then
 MsgBox "Please enter UserName", vbInformation, "Username required"
 Me.txtUserName.SetFocus

ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
 MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password required"
 Me.txtPassword.SetFocus

Else

 If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "Users", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "' And UserPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
 MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!"

 Else

  TempID = Me.txtUername.Value

 Username = DLookup("[UserName]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 TempPass = DLookup("[UserPassword]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 UserLogin = DLookup("[UserLogin]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 
DoCmd.Close
 
If (TempPass = "password") Then
 MsgBox "Please change Password", vbInformation, "New password required"
 DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserinfo", , , "[UserLogin] = " & UserLogin

Else
   'Open different form according to user level
   If userLevel = 1 Then 'For Admin
   DoCmd.OpenForm "Training"
Else
   'For Trainee
   DoCmd.OpenForm "Form", acNormal, , "ID = & TempID 'TempID finds the lastname from UserLogin and I need the number from UserName
   
 End If
 End If
End If
End Sub
```

The "Form" that opens has a Combobox that controls which records show. How do I get the logged in user information to pass to the "Form" based on UserName? if that's even the correct way! Thank you all for you help in advance.

Comment: Brian, thank you for cleaning up my post. It was a mess and hard to read.

Comment: I've been working on the coding and I think that i'm closer to what I want it to do.  For the final line 'For Trainee: DoCmd.OpenForm "Form", I changed it to: DoCmd.OpenForm "Form", acNormal, , "ID = " & TempID.  The ID points to the ID field on my second form. When the code is ran I get a popup that asks for the parameter for the field. When I manually type in the number of the PK that matches the record it opens form 2 to the correct record for the logged in user. How do I get the PK number to carry forward?

Comment: I made some changes and I think that I'm really close to what I need. From the above comment where I added the "..."ID = " & TempID" when the form opens it asks for the PK number that is tied to the name. In the open form I have "Filter on load" set to "yes" and I can see "ID = name" on the filter line.  I need the number that is listed in the userName column vs the name that is in the userLogin column. I've tried creating a second TempID2 that performs a DLookup of the userName and could not get it to work.